# Multiple ajax forms in same page does not work properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a problem with multiples ajax forms in index view, only first works with `remote: true` attribute.
This is my index view with a forms

```
  <% @mensagens.each do |mensagem| %>
  <%= form_for(mensagem, remote: true,:authenticity_token => true) do |f| %>
  <div class="row">    
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <div class="widget">        
        <!-- BLOCK -->

          <div class="row innerAll half border-bottom">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div class="media-body">
                <div class="innerAll half">
                  <div class='col-md-10'><%= f.number_field :avaliacao %></div>
                  <div class='col-md-2'><%= mensagem.slug %></div>
                </div>                    
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row innerAll half border-bottom">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div class="media-body">
                <div class="innerAll half">
                  <%= f.text_area :texto, :class=>"col-md-12 form-control", :placeholder=>"Mensagem" %>
                </div>                    
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row innerAll half border-bottom">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div class="media-body">
                <div class="innerAll half ">
                  <div class="col-md-2"><%= f.check_box :aprovado %></div>
                  <div class="col-md-2"><%= f.check_box :status %></div>
                  <div class="col-md-6 btn"><%= f.text_field :autor,:class=>"form-control", :placeholder=>"Autor" %></div> 
                  <div class="col-md-2"><%= f.submit "Salvar", :class=>"btn btn-success" %></div>
                </div>                    
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="row innerAll half border-bottom">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div class='notyfy_wrapper mensagem_<%= mensagem.id %>'>
                <div class="notyfy_message">
                  <span class="notyfy_text">
                    <div id="alerta"></div>
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>          

      </div>
      <!-- BLOCK -->
    </div>



  </div>

  <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

This is a result: (http://droido.com.br/html.html)

[image]

This first form works fine! but second, send a normal request (non-ajax) and redirect to show page!

Comment: It's hard to see from that screengrab what your problem is.  Also there's only one form, remote or otherwise, in the template code you posted.

Comment: @MaxWilliams There is a loop, so any number of forms could be created.

Comment: @Luiz Could you post the relevant generated html? You aren't happening to test this with one instance twice?

Comment: @MaxWilliams tnks for comment! looh generated all forms!

Comment: @noel link to generated html http://droido.com.br/html.html

 tnks for comments! :)

Comment: @LuizCarvalho Both forms submit with ajax for me in Chrome. I would try watching a console and logs. It is likely some javascript error is causing the setup to fail leaving the form in its default state.

Comment: @noel I will send my code to production, and share with you! very thanks!

Comment: @noel sorry for the delay! http://droido.com.br/mensagens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At droido.com.br/mensagens the second form is nested inside the first. It appears the second  This is why it isn't being set up with ajax, as forms are not supposed to be nested, so I expect Rails is not getting to it.

The problem is, based upon your code above, I am not finding any missing close tags. On the page it looks like the `<div class='row'>` is missing the closing tag. I suggest you knock out a section at a time until you find the problem. Or, delete the entire content and add back until you find it.

Have you used the Chrome dev tools? If not, try it out. Go to the web page, right click, inspect. It will show the tags in a hierarchical manner.